# EDIT mysql tablename to combine with value of one column (concatenate)

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, concatenation, create-table

I have a table called `'Details'`, the Details table has a few columns, one being `'TicketNumber'`.

What I am hoping to do is name the table `'Details_TicketNumber'` --- not the actual word but the value of the first/highest ticket number.

e.g if the TicketNumber is '12345'

the table name would be `Details_12345`

How would I be able to do this? I've been searching for a few hours and no luck today.. Thanks

This is what I have tried (and realized it wouldn't work)

attempt 1:

```
Rename table details 
to  (select concat("details",details.ticketnumber));
```

Attempt 2:

```
set @sql = CONCAT(details,
                  details.TicketNumber)
                 );

prepare s from @sql;

execute s;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create Tables with Dynamic Names via Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889126/create-tables-with-dynamic-names-via-stored-procedure)

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea. What ever you are trying to do - there is a better way.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I agree, but I have been asked to make this happen. thanks

Comment: @JeffUK his recommendation is the way because you have not displayed to us what you have tried.

Comment: @mcv I'll post up my attempt now

Comment: @mcv JeffUK's post is close but I was hoping to edit already existing tables rather than create them, as I realize now that I need to actually have the data in there first.

Comment: @SS360 even though different it is the model for the solution you want to implement. Refer to my posted solution. I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @JeffUK and the [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889126/create-tables-with-dynamic-names-via-stored-procedure) he pointed out. I believe this should work inside a stored procedure.

```
DECLARE highest_ticket INT DEFAULT 0;

SELECT MAX(ticket_number) INTO highest_ticket 
FROM details;

set @s = CONCAT('RENAME TABLE details to details_',highest_ticket); 
prepare renameTable from @s;
EXECUTE renameTable ;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE renameTable ;
```

Comment: Thank you! this is exactly what I needed.